# Add class to parent div that matches label text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a `class` to each parent `div` and have that class match the content of the `label` within the div with a hyphen added between each word.

In the example below, the first div would have class `child-1-name`, the second `child-1-last-name`, the third `child-1-age`. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Note that the HTML is generated automatically.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to loop through all the `.wrapable` elements, retrieve their closest `div` ancestor and then set the class on that to the text of the `label`, with a basic `replace()` operation on the whitespace, something like this:

```js
$('.wrapable').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.closest('div').addClass($el.text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you get all the `label` elements. After you fetch the parent `div` element and add the `textContent` of the `label` as `className` of that `div`.

```js
;window.onload = function(){
  for(var tListOfLabels=document.querySelectorAll('label'), i=tListOfLabels.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    if(tListOfLabels[i].textContent){
      var tDiv = function fP(e){return e && e.tagName === 'DIV' ? e : fP(e.parentNode)}(tListOfLabels[i]);
      tDiv.className += tListOfLabels[i].textContent.split(' ').join('-')
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch each `.wrapable` class and add a class to its `closest` 'div'.
Using Regex replace for spaces into hyphens.

```js
$('.wrapable').each(function() {
  var _this = $(this);

  _this.closest('div').addClass(_this.text().replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple way to do it: just find the text, remove whitespace on the outside, convert to lowercase, and replace all other whitespace with dashes.

```js
$(".wrapable").each(function(i, el) {
  var className = el.innerText.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  $(el).closest('div').addClass(className);
});
```

```css
.child-1-name {background: pink;}
.child-1-last-name { background: lightgreen;}
.child-1-age {background: lightblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code, hope it will help.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"/></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"/></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"/></span>
  </span>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapable").each(function() {
      //   alert($(this).text());
      var data = $(this).text();
      $(this)
        .closest("div")
        .addClass(
          $(this)
            .text()
            .trim()
            .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
        );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an plain JavaScript solution without using jQuery:

Take a look at my comments to understand whats going on.

```js
toarray(document.getElementsByTagName('div')).forEach(div => {  // loop throug each parent
  toarray(div.getElementsByTagName('label')).forEach(label => {  // loop throug each lable
    addclass(label.innerText, div);  // get innerText of label and call the function
  });
});

function toarray(items) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(items);
  // done this to make 'forEach' available on 'getElementsByTagName'
}

function addclass(src, target) {
  src = src.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '-');  // replace all ' ' with '-'
  target.classList.add(src);  // add class to parent div
  
  console.log(target);  // output to show that its working
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 last name</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="req"></span>
  <span>
    <label class="wrapable">child 1 age</label>
    <span class="net"><input type="text"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```